# Load images into numpy array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am trying to load a bunch of image pixel data into a numpy array but facing issues with figuring out how to populate the dtype field.

My images are 128 x 128 x 3 in size with type uint8 and are loaded as follows:

```
import glob
from scipy import misc
images = np.fromiter((misc.imread(path) for path in glob.glob('images/*.png')), <dtype_field>)
```

`misc.imread` loads each image as a numpy array, but the issue I am facing is turning this list of images itself into a numpy array.

Tried the following as well but doesn't work:

```
images = [misc.imread(path) for path in glob.glob('extra_signs/*.png')]
images = np.asarray(images)
```

Where i get the following error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128,128)

Setting dtype to `np.uint8` throws the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

**Note:** I've looked around stackoverflow, I found questions on how to read an image into a numpy array, but none on reading all the images into a single array.

Comment: It looks like one of your images is not 128x128x3.  Are you sure there isn't a monochrome image with shape 128x128 among your files?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Is `monochrome image` just a fancy word for `grayscale` image?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You were almost right. Turns out I had an image with a depth of 4 channels. Not sure what went wrong there but I replaced it with another one that had a normal depth of 3 and it worked. Thanks Warren!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Please post this as an answer so I can accept it and close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the size all the images that you are reading.  Apparently at least one of them is not 128x128x3.